# Do you have to ship proto files with your project?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm making a game engine in c++ and working with protocol-buffers for the first time. I'm not sure if I need to have my proto files accessible by the running game in order to serialize and deserialize objects.

I ask this because I'm using `util::MessageToJsonString` and it's crashing trying to load the proto file. I assume this means it's needed, but I'm curious if there's any way to configure the generator to put the required information in the generated c++? Seems strange to me that it would try to load the .proto file... I figured it would have everything it needs in the message descriptor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got confused, proto files do not need to be shipped with the project.

I had shutdown protobuf before trying to serialize a message. While debugging I saw the name of my protobuf file being used. This was a red herring.

Comment: If someone wants to provide a more detailed explanation possibly explaining how the descriptor cache works in serialization I can mark that as the accepted answer.